# R: lubridate with ts() gives wrong date

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate, quantmod

I am working with some data from the FRED and I try to convert the data to a time series with weekly observation. I use the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
getSymbols('WALCL',src='FRED')
assets <- ts(WALCL, frequency = 365.25/7, end = decimal_date(ymd("2020-07-15")))
```

But instead of the end date being set to 2020-07-15 it is always set to 2021 and the start date to 2003  instead of 2002. The same thing happens when I specify the start date instead. When I try to specify both I get the error `Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) :  invalid time series parameters specified`.

Is there something obvious I am missing or is there an error with the data I downloaded or with `lubridate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
decimal_date(ymd("2020-07-15")) == max(time(assets))
```

You will get a comforting `TRUE`. In your enviornment you see 2021, but I think that it is a rounding issue. If you build your time series with `end = decimal_date(ymd("2020-05-15"))`, 2021 disappears, right?

Comment: I got `TRUE` and changing to 05 also worked. Is there a way I can check from where to where my time series goes other than looking into the environment?

Comment: Recall that in your `assets` a date is a numeric object where the date is expressed as a fraction of its year. `range(time(assets))` gives you the range of the dates in that format.